# Start function if HTML <audio> tag starts the song

Tags: html, function, audio

I want to start a function if someone turn the music on.

```
<audio controls autobuffer>
  <source src="./songs/test.mp3" />
</audio>
```

So I use the standard controls and if someone clicks the play button I want to start a function.

Can someone help me?
I don't find a solution...

Yours Alex.

Thanks for your help.

I got the solution here:

```
function playSound() {
  // source is global so we can call .noteOff() later.
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.addEventListener(
  'play',
  function(e) {
      alert($('audio source').attr('src'));
    // Do Something.
  },
  false
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `play` event:

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.addEventListener(
  'play',
  function(e) {
    // Do Something.
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: @AlexKante, use `audio.src`.

Comment: I get it with that: 
function playSound() {
  // source is global so we can call .noteOff() later.
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.addEventListener(
  'play',
  function(e) {
   alert($('audio source').attr('src'));
    // Do Something.
  },
  false
);
}